# Why is RCX not used for passing parameters to system calls, being replaced with R10?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, calling-convention

According to [System V X86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), function calls in the applications use the following sequence of registers to pass integer arguments:

```
rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9
```

But system call arguments (other than syscall number) are passed in another sequence of registers:

```
rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8, r9
```

Why does the kernel use `r10` instead of `rcx` for the fourth argument? Is it somehow related to the fact that `rcx` is not preserved while `r10` is?

Comment: `r10` is used for passing the http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StaticChain pointer, in languages where that's needed (ABI footnote 13 and Figure 3.4 (pg21)).  Otherwise `r10` is caller-saved: i.e. functions are free to use it *without* saving/restoring it.  I don't see any commentary in the ABI about why they chose to use `r10` for syscalls instead of `rcx`.  The kernel does destroy `rcx` and `r11`, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322100/linux-x64-why-does-r10-come-before-r8-and-r9-in-syscalls discussed this question from a different angle.  Some of the comments are relevant, but in the end,  @technosaurus says "I never did track down exactly why rcx was used to save the entry point instead of r10".  So we haven't figured out why they didn't keep the register -> arg mapping for system calls the same as for function calls.  It appears it would have been possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

X86-64 system calls use `syscall` instruction. This instruction saves return address to `rcx`, and after that it loads `rip` from `IA32_LSTAR` MSR. I.e. `rcx` is immediately destroyed by `syscall`. This is the reason why `rcx` had to be replaced for system call ABI.

This same `syscall` instruction also saves `rflags` into `r11`, and then masks `rflags` using `IA32_FMASK` MSR. This is why `r11` isn't saved by the kernel.

So, these changes reflect how the syscall mechanism works. This is why the kernel is forced to declare `rcx` and `r11` as not saved and even can't use them for parameter passing.

Reference: [Intel's Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf), look for `SYSCALL`.