# Define an alternate name (macro) for a register

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, gnu-assembler

Let's say I have the following assembly program:

```
SYS_EXIT    = 60

.globl _start
_start:
    mov $SYS_EXIT,  %eax
    mov $4,         %edi
    syscall
```

Is it possible to set a register name as a variable/label, something like:

```
SYS_EXIT    = 60
SYS_CALL = '%eax'
FIRST_ARG = '%edi'

.globl _start
_start:
    mov $SYS_EXIT,  SYSCALL
    mov $4,         FIRST_ARG
    syscall
```

It just makes things a bit easier for me,  especially with readability.

Comment: You can do it in **NASM** using `%define` preprocessor directives. Those are textual keywords replaced by different keywords or numbers. Not sure about gas.

Comment: If you use preprocessed assembly, then you can `#define` it. Otherwise the x86 version of `gas` does not support that. The arm version does, but that doesn't help you :)

Comment: @Jester by preprocessed do you mean using `gcc` command instead of `as` ?

Comment: Yes, with `.S` extension `gcc` runs the preprocessor for you. Otherwise you can run it yourself too.

Comment: You might think this would help, but it very quickly introduces new problems.  e.g. if you have to use EAX or EDX explicitly for a `div` instruction, it's easy to not notice that they're the same registers as SYS_CALL and THIRD_ARG when you have 2 different names for the same reg.  If you use any register-name macros, you basically need to use macros for *every* name (at least for some subset of the registers that's easy to remember) or else you'll very quickly make your code harder to debug, except with disassembly view in a debugger which gets your macros out of the way.

Comment: It's not that hard to remember the x86-64 SysV ABI's calling conventions; it follows logically from a couple design ideas: [What's the best way to remember the x86-64 System V arg register order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63892271).  I'd recommend doing that instead of macroing register names unless you're trying to write portable asm with macros to handle different calling conventions on different OSes.

Comment: @PeterCordes good question/answer on that. Yea I always find it difficult to remember the register orders -- esp %r10 before %r8 and %r9.