# Using linkat() in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, system-calls

I'm trying to write a basic exploit in shell code using the linkat() function but I'm new to assembly so I think I'm missing something simple.

```
.globl _start
_start:
.intel_syntax noprefix
        mov rax, 2
        lea rdi, [rip+source]
        mov rsi, 0
        syscall

        mov rax, 265
        mov rdi, 3
        lea rsi, [rip+path]
        mov rdx, 4
        lea rcx, [rip+target]
        mov r8, 0
        syscall
path:
        .string "."
source:
        .string "/flag"
target:
        .string "/foo"
```

But when I debug the code using strace the fourth argument (the destination name) is getting passed as an address e.g. `0x1` vs a string.
Output

```
open("/flag", O_RDONLY)                 = 4
linkat(3, ".", 4, 0x1, 0)               = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

How can I fix this so the fourth argument shows as `/foo` ?

Comment: syscall convention does not use `rcx` for an argument as that is destroyed by the `syscall` instruction. Use `r10` instead.

Comment: thanks that worked! I found a relevant thread based on your feedback https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253144/why-is-rcx-not-used-for-passing-parameters-to-system-calls-being-replaced-with